# how to set mmap for better performance of raw socket

Tags: networking, programming

```
req.tp_block_size=96;
req.tp_frame_size=96;
req.tp_block_nr=2;
req.tp_frame_nr=2;
if ( (setsockopt(fd,
SOL_PACKET,
PACKET_RX_RING,
(char *)&req,
sizeof(req))) != 0 ) {
perror("setsockopt()");
close(fd);
return 1;
};
/* mmap() the sucker */
map=mmap(NULL,
req.tp_block_size * req.tp_block_nr,
PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

1. if minimum size of frame is 64, is the final 4 octet. crc. set by operating system?
   if i set size of frame as 60 without crc place, can it be successfully transfer among cisco router and switch?
2. can above minimum setting work for setting allocation of the circular buffer (ring )option: PACKET_TX_RING

Example
    tp_block_size= 4096 // Minimal size of contiguous block 
    tp_frame_size= 2048 // Size of frame 
    tp_block_nr= 4// Number of blocks 
    tp_frame_nr= 8// Total number of frames, redundant

4096/2048 = 2, 2*4 = 8

what is the size of tpacket_hdr? is it 32 bytes
size of tpacket_hdr + frame with size 64

what is minimum tp_frame_size? is it = 32+64 = 96

tp_block_size= 96
tp_frame_size= 96
tp_block_nr  = 2
tp_frame_nr  = 2

96/96 = 1, 1*2 = 2

if number of block is less, can it have better performance? or more blocks is better?

if every frame is just 64, and send immediately when have msg
ret = sendto(sock, buffer, pkt_index->pktlen, MSG_DONTWAIT,
                         (struct sockaddr *)(void *) to, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

1. (bonus not needed to answer) how to see the difference between applied above and not applied?